# Enabling 2FA on Debian 10, but only for passwords (pubkey without 2FA)

Tags: debian, ssh, 2-factor-authentication

I admin my private server 99% of the time from one of my own machines, using pubkey authentication. However, I have password auth enabled (for my user, not for root) for the rare cases where I need to access it from another machine, which has happened.

To increase the security of the system, I'd like to enable 2FA but only for password login. I very much appreciate the convenience of logging in without any prompting using pubkey auth, and would rather go without 2FA than having to use that every time (I work on confidential projects and I already do a dozen or more 2FA auths on a typical working day).

All the guides I found for setting up 2FA assume that you want 2FA active across all auth methods.

Can I - and if so, how - enable 2FA only for password authentication, but not for pubkey?

If that doesn't work, my workaround would be to disable password auth for my regular user and set up a maintenance user who has 2FA enabled. But I'd prefer a more clean setup.

Answer (score 1):

This is speculation, so there is definitely some tweaking that needs to be done, but the behavior you describe is definitely possible.

You can setup your PAM auth config with something like:

```
auth       sufficient    pam_ssh_user_auth.so
auth       required      password-auth
auth       required      pam_2fa.so
```

This config file is read in-order. The first line says, 'if ssh authentication has worked, this is sufficient. Exit success.' Assuming you have ssh public key auth enabled, this would cause successful auths to exit. The next two lines are only run if we haven't used the public key yet. We simply include the appropriate password-auth and 2fa auth.